# Jquery Ajax post, returns what type of data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, types, return

I sent an ajax request and it either returns the word "false" or "Username". I got this to work fine. On success it puts the word "false" or the "Username" into the .body class div. The problem I am having is that I want to check if "false", or not "false" exists. So that my password field can disable or undisable. The thing is everything works fine and is tested. My issue is that when I check the "false" it thinks that it exists as NULL. Whatever the ajax sends out it is a foreign data type, although it can display it in html, I can seem to then store it in a variable and check if "false" exists.

```
$(function () {

    $(".Guide_Welcome_Container").hide();
    $("#inputPassword").attr("disabled", "disabled");


    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".Guide_Welcome_Container").fadeToggle(1000);
        $(".HeaderLogin").fadeToggle(1000);
    });

    $("#inputEmail").keyup(function () {
        var UsernameInput = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PullUserDb.php",
            data: {
                'UsernameInput': UsernameInput
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#BodyID').html(data);
                var GoodUsername = $("#BodyID").html();

                if (GoodUsername != "false") {
                    $("#inputPassword").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                    $("#inputPassword").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                //
            }

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#BodyID").html()  //might contain some html too`

Try 

`console.log($("#BodyID").html());`

within your success callback to see what it returns

Comment: i added the console.log($("#BodyID").html());  and nothing came up. Is it suppose to be an alert?

Comment: No you will need to use the browser dev tools to inspect the page. You can right click on the page and click inspect element and then click on the console tab

Comment: Thanks. It returns the word false, or the username. It is returning the words but the If else statement still no worky.

Comment: @james You can also try `alert(typeof GoodUsername)` to check if your data is a string and if it is make sure it's in lowercase...

Comment: I found the problem using your console.log trick. The problem is, is that it is returning a bunch of white space before the output of 'false' or 'username'. I will have to think of how to fix it. Thanks though. (also it was not a time issue, i tried this aswell.)

Comment: I also tried the alert. It is a string. I also tried the alert without the typeof. It is also returning alot of whitespace. That is the issue.

Comment: @james try `GoodUsername.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` to get rid of the white spaces... Thought it is always best to use json dataType as suggested by StupidDev.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

```
dataType: "html"
```

try json instead of html :)
i user this struct

```
{success:true,message:'OK'}
```

Comment: This is a best practice in my book.

Comment: I made it json. Still no luck.

Comment: How do u use it ? Test response data, it must be Json syntax, so javascript can parse it to Json object

Comment: when i use json it will now only return false or nothing. I don't get a username returned. It's broke with json datatype.

Comment: I think it needs a pause. The data is always null when going through true and false.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your success function (I'm assuming you're being returned the string `'false'`, not a boolean, but if I'm wrong, swap out `'false'` for `false`):

```
if (data !== 'false') {
    // 1. put username on the page, like you do in the above code
    // 2. enable password field
} else {
    // disable password field
}
```

No need to put it on the page, then check what you put on the page. You're already being returned the username in the `data` object.

Comment: Did not work it still see's NULL. If i do (data !== 'false' && data != NULL) then is will stay disabled. You think maybe the if statement runs to fast, before ajax has time to populate data?