# Mistake in transferring between PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP file and JavaScript file.

JavaScript transfers 3 variables into PHP file, PHP file transfers the result into JavaScript. The process is working and gives me the right result, however as a last action in JavaScript when I checking the result it is give me false instead of true. So please help me to find out what is wrong.

PHP:

```
if ((isset($_POST['st'])) && (!empty($_POST['st'])))
{
    $status=$_POST['st'];
    switch($status)
    {
        case '0': {

            break;
        }
        case "1": {  

            $login = $_POST['login'];
            $pas = $_POST['pas'];
            check($login,$pas);
            break;
        }
    }
exit;
}



function check ($login,$pas) {
include "php/log_bd.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Login='$login'",$db); //I know, i know, that it is dangerous in case of SQL injection, but I use it for educational example.
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($row))
{
    exit('er');             
} 
if ($row['Pas']!= $pas)
{
    exit('er');
}

exit(0);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on("click","input[name=door_open]", function () {

var login = $("input[name=login]").val();
var pas = $("input[name=pas]").val();

$.post("index.php",{ st:1, login:login , pas:pas} ,function(data)
        {

        alert (data); // I have 'er'
            if (data == 'er')
                {
                    alert ("Sorry incorrect data");
                        return false;
                }
            else 
                {alert (data);}
        });
return false;
});
```

So It give me in JavaScript file 'er' result but when I check data == 'er', it told me that it is false.

As was suggested I add some some log console comands
[image]

Comment: I want to know which error you are getting. `empty($row)` or `($row['Pas']!= $pas)`

Comment: It could be == vs ===.  Look here for explanation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-JavaScript-comparisons

Comment: i tried the === instead of ==, but it is still the same problem/

Comment: I did test and the error I get from -  empty($row), and it is right because there is no data in the base.

Comment: Please check this.. and tell me if it works or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847938/jquery-ajax-post-returns-what-type-of-data

Comment: tested and working. Server returns "er"   `Sorry incorrect data`

Comment: -manta- Are you sure that you didn't add anything? because it still gave me wrong answer

Comment: undefined  -  it is what i found in cosole in result of action described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847938/jquery-ajax-post-returns-what-type-of-data

Comment: just console log `data` and share what you see.

Comment: The php if statement fails at `empty()`, 'er' is returned.

Comment: -manta- yes 'er' is returned but when it is came to comparison it doesn't give me 'incorect data'

Comment: Remove the `alert` before your `if` statement. It's not needed as we already know 'er' is returned. I would do as other have said and change all  `alert()` to `console.log()` for readability and flow.

Comment: if(data == "er") should return false according to you code. changing it to if(data != "er") will not return false

Comment: -kenny west- you are not right,  the data = "er" , and in comparison - data=="er" must to give true not false.

Comment: Hi alex.. i just told to console log data. remove `$('#main')` stuffs

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `data == "\ner"` work?

Comment: @JCOC611 no, checked that already (with the code supplied). There may be other echo's not listed.

Comment: @manta all echo's and exit's  is listed in the code above. all functions have exits in the end that avoid any collusions with other functions.

Comment: Ohk.. Just trim the data and then check... `$.trim(data) == 'er'`

Comment: @JCOC611 with the updated image, you are in fact correct ;) there is a new line char.

Comment: @JCOC611 "\ner" is worked

Comment: @akhilp2255 "\ner" is worked? I think trim will work too.

Comment: @akhilp2255 Can you explain why he return \ner instead of er ... Just for future people who will got the same problem, and to close out the question.

Comment: @JCOC611 Can you explain why he return \ner instead of er ... Just for future people who will got the same problem, and to close out the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped me to find the mistake in the code.

Comment: Check out the steps given in those answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11593384/2919789